# How to get the option id instead of the shown string in the Autocomplete component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

i am doing a project using React, material-ui and redux-form. Long story short: The select fields than i am using currently, sometimes have many options, so the users are asking for a select with search.

To make this i am trying to use the autocomplete component in the lab section of material ui:

```
<Autocomplete
      options={options}
      style={{ width: '80%', padding: '10px '}}
      getOptionLabel={ options => (options.nombres +" "+options.apellidos) }
      renderOption={ (options, status) => {
        return (options.nombres + " " + options.apellidos)
      }}
      renderInput={params => { console.log(params); return(<TextField 
        { ...params} 
        label={label}
        fullWidth
    />)}}
```

The problem here is that when i submit the form the value of the field is the string that i am showing with getOptionLabel but instead i need to show the name but get the value Id when a submit the form.. Will be really hepfull if you guys could give me a hand with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use hooks for this:

```js
const Sample = () => {
  const [autocomplete, setAuto] = React.useState(null);

  const handleAutocomplete = (event, newValue) => {
    if (newValue != null) {
    console.log(newValue.id)
    setAuto(newValue);
    }
  }


  return (
    <Autocomplete
          options={options}
          style={{ width: '80%', padding: '10px '}}
          getOptionLabel={ options => (options.nombres +" "+options.apellidos) }
          onChange={handleAutocomplete}
          renderInput={params => ( <TextField
            { ...params}
            label="Selecciona..."
            fullWidth/>
          )}
          />
        );
};

const options = [
  {
  nombres: 'Juan García',
  apellidos: 'Oliver',
  id: 1,
  },
  {
  nombres: 'Melchor',
  apellidos: 'Martínez',
  id: 2,
  },
  {
  nombres: 'Ricardo',
  apellidos: 'Sanz',
  id: 3,
  },
]


export default Sample;
```

Comment: Hello Yuri, that make sense, is a nice solution but idk how to implement that one with redux-form.. that is part of  the problem that i have... do you have any other idea for that?

Comment: Hey Yuri, what i did was the same but instead of using the state of the component i used the redux-form change function... now i have a last doubt... is there any problem of sync doing that???... because i asume that as soon as the value change react redux call that function under the hood.. and then i call it again in my handleChange function to assign another value to it